How to apply for Turkey eVisa as a Pakistani passport holder with US valid visa?
I am Pakistani passport holder with US valid visa, I have a transit in turkey for 22 hours. What options (cheapest) do I have for visa if I want to exit the airport for the time? And how do I apply for quickest visa?

Pakistani passport holders are required to have a visa to leave the airport and visit Turkey. Because you have a valid US visa, you are eligible to apply online for an e-visa without visiting a Turkish consulate. As of this writing, a Turkish e-visa for eligible Pakistani citizens costs USD 60 plus USD 6 processing fee, for a total of $66, and is usually issued nearly-instantly online. This is both cheaper and faster than any other way of obtaining a Turkish visa; for example, applying for a visa in person in Pakistan costs USD 180 and is a process involving in-person visits to the service center.
